# Need to cut off useless text from cmd output

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

i have output of amd-smi command:

```
====================    ROCm System Management Interface    ====================
================================================================================
 GPU  Temp    AvgPwr   SCLK     MCLK     Fan      Perf    SCLK OD
  1   69.0c   67.162W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  10  69.0c   71.230W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  68.63%   manual    0%
  11  67.0c   69.137W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  47.84%   manual    0%
  2   70.0c   72.98W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  3   69.0c   67.169W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  4   68.0c   70.231W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  5   68.0c   70.176W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  6   68.0c   71.89W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  7   69.0c   70.186W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  8   71.0c   67.25W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
  9   68.0c   68.152W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%   manual    0%
================================================================================
====================           End of ROCm SMI Log          ====================
```

and i want to get:

```
 GPU  Temp    AvgPwr   SCLK     MCLK     Fan   
  1   70.0c   67.174W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  68.63%
  10  69.0c   71.239W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%
  11  67.0c   69.148W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  47.84%
  2   68.0c   72.52W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%
  3   67.0c   67.92W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  31.76%
  4   68.0c   70.235W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  47.84%
  5   70.0c   70.78W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  68.63%
  6   71.0c   71.168W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  68.63%
  7   71.0c   71.76W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  68.63%
  8   71.0c   67.77W   960Mhz   1750Mhz  68.63%
  9   68.0c   68.174W  960Mhz   1750Mhz  47.84%
```

I have done before `amd-smi | sed '/=/d' | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'` and this helps me to delete useless lines. But niw i need to cut some text.

Comment: What have you searched for and what did you find? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work

```
amd-smi | sed -e '/=/d' -e 's/Perf//' -e 's/manual//' -e 's/SCLK OD//' -e 's/0%//'
```

Or,

```
amd-smi | sed -E -e '/=/d' -E -e 's/Perf|manual|SCLK OD|0%//g'
```

Comment: first is worked like a charm!

in second i have:
`amd-smi | sed -E -e '/=/d' -E -e 's/Perf|manual|SCLK OD|0%//g'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...


GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

So i will youe a first one

Answer (score 1):

You could try with an awk one-liner that looks like this:

```
awk '$1 !~ /=/ {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' yourfile.txt
```

Searches for lines that don't contain (or start with if you wish `/^=/`) and '=', then prints first 6 fields.

note: I've dumped your input in a file, of course you would pipe awk instead of sed.

Comment: wow, thats higly customisable solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '!/=/{print gensub(/((\s*\S+){6}).*/, "\\1", 1)}'
```

Comment: thank you it, also woks good. 
In this case i will choose a sed solution due it readability. I have some collegues in support, who cant manage such awk expression yet :)

Comment: @navy OK, but when e. g. some SPI device is overclocked or one of the FANs is inactive, the output table will have an invalid format.